# how to use SHOULD inside MUST in elasticsearch6?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new to elasticsearch trying to understand things better but struggling a bit. I am trying to write query with AND(must) and OR(should) condition. Below elasticsearch query works good. But I need one more zipcode to be added in the condition, it should be or between 2 zipcodes.

Working Query:

```
    {
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "Name",
      "Address",
      "Contact"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "firstName",
              "lastName",
              "middleName"
            ],
            "query": "*andy*"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "zipcode": "55555"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

how to add zipcode value match in OR condition?

Comment: Whenever I ask question my score goes down. :p have to improve. Whoever gives minus one please let me know why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either replace `match` by `terms`:

```
    {
      "terms": {
        "zipcode": ["55555", "55556"]
      }
    }
```

Or you can add two `match` clauses in a `bool/should`:

```
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "fields": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName",
          "middleName"
        ],
        "query": "*andy*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "minimum_should_match": 1,
  "should": [
    {
      "match": {
        "zipcode": "55555"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "zipcode": "55556"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The second query worked. The first one I tried it already, its not working may because of elasticsearch6 not sure.

Comment: First one should work, too. but glad the second worked out